# phpmyadmin from cmd line

Tags: windows, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to query the database in phpMyAdmin from the command line in windows and not use the web interface ? Like export database from the command line istead of going to the web interface to do so,

We are trying to provide some kind of automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is a web interface that will only be available through a browser. However this is just pretty front-end to the MySQL server.

The `mysql` command line client is the most useful, but `mysqldump` provides a command-line version of exporting the database. For `mysql` you can pass a query rather than get a shell session - `mysqldump` is just a utility that takes command line arguments. Both are suitable for 'some sort of automation'.

Comment: But I cannot use mysql command line client to export database which is in the phpmyadmin server. Can I ?

Comment: And if not, why would I install phpmyadmin on my machine if I can use it on the internet ?

Comment: Firstly your database is not in phpMyAdmin. Your database is on a MySQL server which phpMyAdmin connects to (might be the same computer). So yes, you can use a client on the same server (or remotely if it is set-up correctly).

People install phpMyAdmin to provide a simple and visual method of viewing the MySQL database. It is, by design, less functional than the client, but easier for people to use.

Comment: I get it, so I need to install php, mysql and phpmyadmin to be able to do that.

Comment: And if I've an account in phpmyadmin, is it the same account to be used for mysql server ?

Comment: Yes - it just uses the MySQL user accounts. You don't need to install PHP or phpMyAdmin to install the command line client for MySQL.